# Can "Recent Posts" widget be filtered by functions.php?

Tags: theme-development

I have my own "Recent Posts" menu, but its not currently implemented as a Widget. I'm just including it in sidebar.php.

I had to "roll my own" so to speak in order to filter the menu of certain categories whose posts I don't want to appear in the menu.

Would it be possible, via functions.php, to filter the default "Recent Posts: widget's menu items in order to exclude posts belonging to a specific category?

If so, I'd really be grateful for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no filter for `WP_Query` args in `WP_Widget_Recent_Posts` class, so it's impossible. I think there are plugins for recent post that have category filtering option - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/recent-posts

Comment: Thanks Mamaduka. I believe that my approach will then need to be to clone the recent posts widget and create my own version of it. I've posted a new question with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 3.4.0, it's possible to filter the argument to the query.

```
add_filter('widget_posts_args', 'wpse_30124');

function wpse_30124(){
  return array(
    'posts_per_page'      => $number,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'cat' => '-12' // term_id of the category you want to exclude
  );
}
```

More info [class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_recent_posts/widget/)